# Permission denied after renaming repository

Tags: git, github

After working on a project for some time (with lots of commits to github), originally cloned from a starter project, I changed the name of the project on github, and immediately afterword all `git push origin` fail with "Permission denied (publickey)".

Now checking github settings, there are no longer ssh keys attached to my account. I am confused as to what/why this happened.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+rename+repository

Comment: Esp. see the point 5 at the accepted answer.

Comment: ugh. i had been using http, not ssh. that was my issue. go ahead and close